# Prove that $A \cup (B \triangle C) = A \triangle (B \backslash (A \cup C)) \triangle (C \backslash (A \cup B))$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

We just proved in the [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/9586954528) that the symmetric difference is associative, so the above expression makes sense.

However, I have no idea how to tackle this problem, I tried using the definitions and some basic properties of the algebra of sets, but I can't come up with anything that even resembles the result. I know results like this  can be proven using the characteristic function, but I would rather avoid proofs like that since that hasn't been introduced in the text yet, for now we're supposed to just use algebra of sets, no double inclusion either.

Any help would be appreciated, if possible also some general remarks on how to deal with proofs that include the symmetric difference, since the book has a lot of exercises with those and I have no idea how to tackle them.

Thanks.

Comment: Which book are you referring to?

Comment: @Shaun The book is called "Matemática Estructural" by Andrés Forero Cuervo, not sure if it has an english translation. [here](https://www.amazon.com/-/es/Andr%C3%A9s-FORERO-CUERVO/dp/9586954528).

Comment: Thank you. Please [edit] the question accordingly. (Not everyone checks the comments.)

Comment: From [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933): "**Avoid "no clue" questions** 
Too many questions begin or end with "I don't even know how to begin with this problem". While this may be true (you may genuinely have no idea how to approach the problem), it is still not a valid reason to limit your post to the statement of the problem without any mention of your own thoughts. Such questions will most of the time be rejected by the community, which represents a significant waste of time..."

Comment: Over time, you will get it. My first questions here were terrible, and even before I learned and improved, I would always get an answer or some guidance, as it is the need to share expertise and teach others that keep the wheels turning. It is always a good idea to share definitions so we know where the issue begins. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know that $\Delta$ is associative and commutative and $A\Delta A = \emptyset$, $A\Delta \emptyset = A$. So it is enough to show that

$$A \Delta ( A\cup (B\Delta C)) = (B\backslash(A\cup C)) \cup (C \backslash (A \cup B))$$

Now $A\Delta E) = (A\backslash E)\cup (E \backslash A)$. Therefore we have to show that

$$(A\cup ( B\Delta C) ) \backslash A) = (B\backslash(A\cup C)) \cup (C \backslash (A \cup B))$$
or
$$(B \Delta C) \backslash A = (B\backslash(A\cup C)) \cup (C \backslash (A \cup B))$$

But now $B\Delta C = (B\backslash C) \cup (C \backslash B)$
so
$$(B \Delta C) \backslash A = ((B\backslash C) \cup (C \backslash B)) \backslash A= ((B\backslash C) \backslash A) \cup ((C \backslash B)\backslash A)$$
and we are almost there...

Answer (score 0):

Let $a = A \triangle (B \backslash (A \cup C))$,
$b=(C \backslash (A \cup B))$

If $x\in a \triangle b$, for sure $x\notin a\cap b$. So $x$ can be in $a$, either in $A$ or $B\setminus (A\cup C)$. If $x\in A$ we're done,
Otherwise $x\in B\setminus (A\cup C)$, meaning $x\in B$ and $x\notin C$, so $x\in B\setminus (B\cap C)\subset B\triangle C = (B\cup C)\setminus (B\cap C)$

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

We use the identity $B \backslash (A\cup C))=B \backslash A\cap B \backslash C$ (1).

Observe that $A, B \backslash (A\cup C)$ and $C \backslash (A\cup B)$ are pairwise disjoint. Therefore $A \bigoplus(B \backslash (A\cup C))\bigoplus(C \backslash (A \cup B))=A\cup(B \backslash (A\cup C))\cup(C \backslash (A\cup B))$.

And $A\cup (B \backslash (A\cup C))=A\cup(B \backslash A\cap B \backslash C)=(A\cup B)\cap( A\cup B \backslash C)=A\cup B \backslash C,$ by (1),  distributivity and $A\cup B \backslash C \subseteq A\cup B.$

And similarly, $A\cup(C \backslash (A\cup B))=A\cup C \backslash B$.

Hence $A \bigoplus(B \backslash (A\cup C))\bigoplus(C \backslash (A \cup B))=A\cup(B\bigoplus C).$